# How do I insert pictures into my LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics

I want to insert images into my LaTeX document. I used `\includegraphics{}` and also kept the image in the working directory of the tex file.  But still I am unable to do so.

My image is in GIF format; is that a problem?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{mathtools}    
\usepackage{attrib}    
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\graphicspath{ {images/} }    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{geometry}    
\geometry{a4paper}    
\title{ An Introduction to Multivariable Calculus}    
\newcommand{\lt}{<}    
\newcommand{\gt}{>} 

\begin{document}    
\maketitle    
\includegraphics{fig5-24.jpg}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: the file types that are supported depend (traditionally) on the driver being used not on latex itself, but if you are using pdftex use png or jpg or pdf, you should be able to easily find tools to convert the gif to png

Comment: Now in the tex file it comes out blank. I mean a blank image is shown instead of what it is

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam We don't know, what format you use and what the image looks like. Maybe you did some conversion with some (unknown) tool and the result actually got white. Please provide more information and always show a small example of you documents code in order to help us finding errors.

Comment: You say you use a GIF file but your example document shows JPG. So what is it really? Do you use PDFLaTeX or something else?

Comment: i converted it from gif to jpeg. I use pdflatex

Comment: png would have been a more natural format (being a lossless bitmap format like gif) but either should work.

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam You say that you are keeping the image in your working directory. But you told LaTeX to search for it in `images/`. Please have a look, if you are referencing to the right path.

Comment: why have you got `\newcommand{\lt}{<}   ` ? that just means that you can type the three characters `\lt` instead of the one character `<`  which doesn't seem very useful?